# Mongo db issue to handle the in query with large object id

Tags: python, mongodb

I am uploading the bulk csv contacts to "abc" collection and storing the contact _id to the another "xyz" collection array.

When i search the contacts under "xyz" collection, i am passing the ids with $in query inside collection "abc".

It's working perfect till 10k $in query search, but failed to get 200k $in query search.

I need help to solve the above problem, i will appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: What does `Object.bsonsize()` return if you hand this function the $in document ?

Comment: This will return
Approx 3800160